# How to make serve with more threads with Hunchentoot

Tags: web-services, concurrency, lisp, hunchentoot

I am using Hunchentoot for a web app to be a high traffic db driven app, also depends on web sockets protocol and http ajax requests.
When I benchmark my app with apache benchmark as

`ab -c 50 -n 1000`

connection is reset prompt is shown. for unto 40 concurrency test is completed but after not. How can one increase max-thread-count of Hunchentoot.

What is the realistic numbers of concurrency and request number per unit time for a high traffic web app that I should think according to? for example for reddit or twitter.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a number to the taskmaster with the :max-thread-count keyword.